# How to make use of abstract method overriding?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract

I am learning C# but I have found a problem with going further. I have code like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Planeta Z1 = new Ziemia("matka Ziemia");
            Z1.Nazwa();
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
 
    }
    public abstract class Planeta
    {
        protected string nazwaPlanety;
        public Planeta() { nazwaPlanety = " "; }
        public Planeta(string s) { nazwaPlanety = s; }
        public abstract void Nazwa();        
    }
    public class Ziemia: Planeta
    {
        public Ziemia() { }
        public Ziemia(string s) : base(s){ }
        public override void Nazwa()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(this.nazwaPlanety);
        }
    }    
}
```

but I found two errors:

> Error  1   'ConsoleApplication1.Ziemia' does not implement inherited abstract member 'ConsoleApplication1.Planeta.Nazwa()' Line:   24  Column: 18
>
> Error  2   'ConsoleApplication1.Ziemia.Nazwa(string)': no suitable method found to override    Line: 28    Column: 30

Why I getting errors like so?

How to avoid them and make programm works properly?

Also: I don't know why in second error it showing "string" 'ConsoleApplication1.Ziemia.Nazwa(*string*)' as a type of argument that function would take.

Comment: I've compiled (and run) it. It works.

Comment: Please show your real code. The code you have in your question is ok.

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the application

Comment: Heh... But this is really my code. Clearly copied from my Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express console :/

Comment: Is it possible you have unsaved documents?

Comment: I had one unseaved document, Bingo! Thank you Boluc Papuccuoglu :)

Answer (score 0):

try it a simplier way to eleminate possible issue parameters probably. You can try following console application example. Replace employees with Ziemia, technician Class with "Planeta*.

http://www.codecandle.com/articles/csharp/classes/abstract-classes.html